# Measure preserving action of topological group $G$ on probability space $X$ gives continuous embedding $G \to L^2(X)$?

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups, ergodic-theory

On page 13 of Bekka and Mayer "Ergodic Theory and Topological Dynamics of Group Actions on Homogeneous Spaces" the authors study measure preserving actions of a locally compact topological group $G$ on a probability space $(X, \mu)$. They claim without further comment that given any $f \in L^2(X)$, the map $G \to L^2(X)$ given by $g \mapsto T_g f$ where $T_g f(x) = f(g^{-1} x)$ is continuous. This is not clear to me.

After thinking about it for a while, I think I can prove it if I can prove the seemingly simpler statement that given any measurable set $A$ of $X$, the function $h(g) = \mu(A \cap g.A)$ is a continuous function on $G$. However, I was unable to prove this statement, even in the special case of measure preserving $\mathbb{R}$ actions. I feel like there must be something that I'm missing. I also feel like this must be a standard result, but my Googling attempts were fruitless.

Comment: "measure preserving actions of a locally compact topological group $G$". Where does the topology of $G$ matter in this setup?

Comment: The topology of $G$ is showing up because the measure on $G$ is the Haar measure. Perhaps I should have specified what I mean by measurable action. I mean a map $G \times X \to X$ which is (jointly) measurable and a group action ($G$ has the Haar measure).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The $L^2$-norm is an integral. Use Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem to show what you want.